# Spring boot with native query - entity mapped is null when column value is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, repository, nativequery

I am using native query to get a list of entities in spring boot. Whenever the column value is null, the mapped entity is null.
My Repository looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<OrderKey, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT l.[ORDER_ID]," +
            "l.[KEY_TYPE], " +
            "l.[KEY]," +
            "l.[VERSION]  " +
            "FROM [ORDER_TABLE] l " +
            "WHERE [ORDER_ID] = :orderId",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<OrderKey> findAll(@Param("orderId") Long orderId);

}
```

Entity:

```
public class OrderKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 10L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ORDER_ID")
    public long orderId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "KEY_TYPE")
    public String keyType;

    @Column(name = "KEY")
    public String key;

    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    public String version;

}
```

I have three rows in the database table where two rows have "Version" column with null values.

I am seeing that the List populated has: `{null, null, OrderKeyinstance}`

Can some one help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the contents of the list, maybe your toString method displays only the version and suddenly, we display null, null

Comment: No, the object itself is null

Comment: Have you use the mapper? have you execute the sql displayed on console directly on SGBD?

Comment: No i am not using mapper. Yes the query is correct. The logs in spring boot show the data extracted

Comment: Can you remove @Id annotation on keyType field?

Comment: nope, doesnt help:(

Comment: I think with SQL native, the mapping to entity does not work, it's return List<Object[]>, and you must create your entity via constructor, else use hql : select o from OrderKey o where o.orderKey=: orderId

Comment: I am seeing that it doesnt work even with the default spring boot methods like findAllBy.